# Struggling with a list geofenceList in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-geofence

I tracked my problem down to adding to my geofenceList.

this is a global variable

```
lateinit var geofenceList: MutableList<Geofence>
```

In `onCreate` I add to the list:

```
val latitude = -26.082586
val longitude = 27.777242
val radius = 10f
geofenceList.add(Geofence.Builder()
      .setRequestId("Toets")
      .setCircularRegion(latitude,longitude,radius)
      .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
      .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
      .build())
```

Every time I run the app the app closes as soon as it opens.

I tried changing it to a normal variable but I am not certain how to do it and keep it a global variable, and a List would be more useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like your program is throwing an exception. When you run your app on your phone through Android Studio, you should see a run-tool window which should show you an exception. Please edit your question and paste the exception there or follow the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) to solve your issue. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what your issue is: You never initialize your list. When you follow the advice in my comment, you should find a `NullPointerException` and here's how to fix it:

Firstly, try to avoid `lateinit` if possible. The compiler actually tries to find this problem for you and by using `lateinit`, you basically tell the compiler to shut up - even though the mistake is still there. INstead, you need to initialize your variable like so:

```
var geofenceList: MutableList<Geofence> = mutableListOf()
```

You could make it even shorter by removing the explicit type declaration:

```
var geofenceList = mutableListOf<Geofence>()
```